# DB ASM variable in Inline ASM C++

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly, dos, borland-c++

I'm trying to figure out how to use DB variables from ASM into Inline ASM C++

I have this ASM code:

```
filename db "C:\imagen.bmp"
eti0:
mov ah,3dh 
mov al,0 
mov dx,offset filename 
int 21h
```

and in C++:

```
//ASCII of C:\imagen.bmp plus zero in the end because of int 21h
int filename=6758921051099710310111046981091120;

asm{
    mov ah,3dh 
    mov al,0 
    mov dx,offset filename
    int 21h
}
```

Is this is correct?

Comment: Strangely the inline assembly part looks correct, while the C++ part is completely wrong. Usually it's the other way around here. What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `int` can only hold a 16-bit signed integer and the number you tried to assign to `filename` is way outside its range. As `int` variables are two bytes long, they're not all that useful for storing file names.  Instead you should store the name in an array of `char` like this:

```
char filename[] = "C:\\imagen.bmp";
```

The array will include a zero byte as its final element, as normal for strings in C++.

You could also replace entire thing with:

```
int handle;
_dos_open("C:\\imagen.bmp", 0, &handle);
```

Comment: i get these errors [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Brpjc5Rq-sTGdLNXJmQlpBVEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ah, I should've declared handle as being an `int`. I've updatef my answer accordingly.

Comment: if i use this code: 

`#include<stdio.h>`
`#include<conio.h>`
`#include<iostream.h>`
`#include<dos.h>`
`#include<stdlib.h>`
`#include<fcntl.h>`
`#include<share.h>`

`void main(void)`
`{`
`clrscr();`
`int handle;`
`_dos_open("C:\\imagen.bmp", 0, &handle);`
`cout<<handle;`
`getch();`
`}`

i get a 6 value and a 6 error value corresponds to 06h  Invalid handle

Comment: The 6 value is the value of the handle, not an error value. If you want to check for an error you need to check the return value of `_dos_open`. If it returns 0 then there's no error, anything else is a MS-DOS error code.

Comment: Thanks! there's no errors now. But i'm wondering if you can help me with the next thing i need to do.

i need now to run the next ASM code:
    `unsigned char buffer;
    for(int i=118;i>0;i--){
    asm{
        mov ah,3fh 
        mov bx,handle
        mov dx,offset buffer
        mov cx,1 
        int 21h 
    }
    }`

it's good to use the unsigned char in buffer or i need to use another type?

Comment: @NTHINGs unsigned char is one byte long and you're only reading one byte so the type is OK.

Comment: But it is ok the instruction "offset"?

Comment: @NTHINGs You'll need to use either `lea dx,buffer` or `static unsigned char buffer;`. You could also replace the inline assembly with a call to `_dos_read`.